# Definition of integrable representation of Kac-Moody algebra

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-algebras, infinite-dimensional-manifolds, kac-moody-algebras

I have seen several definitions of integrable representation $V$ of Kac-Moody algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ online. Which one is the standard one? Are they actually equivalent?

First one is $e_i, f_i$ acts locally-nilpotent on $V$, where $e_i, f_i$ are the standard generators of $\mathfrak{g} in the Serre's presentation in Kac's book.

Second one is for any root $\alpha$, restriction of $V$ to the $sl_2$ corresponding to $\alpha$ can be integrated to a $SL_2$ representation.

Third one is $V$ can be lifted to a representation of the (maximal) simply connected Kac-Moody group whose lie algebra is $\mathfrak{g}$.

The case I am interested most is untwisted affine Lie algebra. So feel free to restrict to this case if it helps.

Comment: What in particular has given you trouble in working out the equivalence between the first and second definitions?

Comment: I am not familiar with relation between representations between $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb{C})$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{C})$. For 1 implies 2, I would like to say yet not sure, if $e_i,f_i$ acts locally-nilpotent, then so is $h_i$. But have no idea on why it is true for arbitrary root spaces.

Comment: I have modified definition 1, it should be locally nilpotent instead of nilpotent. Also it is just Serre's generators instead of Chevalley's basis. In fact, this is the definition given in Kac's book.